# Entity Framework 6 - reuse same table in multiple edmx files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx, ef-database-first

I have been tasked with upgrading our software to use EF6. Previously it was using a combination of EF4 & 5.

We use the database first approach. The upgrade went smoothly as far a code changes go, but after running the application and doing a query the following error is thrown.

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'tblAccountMaintenance'.
>
> Previously found CLR type 'DALUsers.StatusDB.tblAccountMaintenance', newly found CLR type 'DALUsers.AccountsDB.tblAccountMaintenance'.

The class in questions, `tblAccountMaintenance`, is generated inside multiple `.tt` files. The classes are references to the same table, just referenced in different `.edmx` files.

Simply removing one of the references is not a good option in this case as we have used a similar strategy with several other tables and would require thousands of lines of rewritten code.

What do I need to do to fix this in EF6?

Comment: Have you tried putting the edmx files in different namespaces?

Comment: Yes, different namespace

Comment: it's required to modify your T4 template file, not just simply by locating the `edmx` files. ***unless*** you create new edmx files (models) and place them in different folders ***initially***.

Comment: Each `edmx` file is in a separate folder; during the migration I deleted all the existing `.tt` files and regenerated them from within the designer. (`Add Code Generation Items...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the the issue (using the same tables, with the same name in multiple `edmx` files in the same project) is related to the fact the the `.tt` files contain new objects that derive from `dbContext` - and this is a limitation/constraint that is specific to `dbContext`.

I downloaded this plugin: **https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a**

Which allows me to create `EF6` `.tt` files that derive from `EnityObject` instead which does not have this constraint.  It also makes it so I don't have to update all of my code to use the newer `dbContext` methods which is a plus.

As a note to others viewing this - this is probably not the best answer if you are starting with a newer project or have a small number of `edmx` files/tables as `EntityObject` is not as robust as `dbContext`, however this is a good band-aid fix - especially if you are like me and going to have to do a complete rewrite when EF7 comes out.